# Почему не запускается страница при создании DB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, eel, веб-интерфейс

Пытаюсь сделать веб-приложение с Базой данных. Выбрал самый типичный и простой пример: To Do List.

Программа запускается, вот только не создаётся страница. То есть, окно браузера появляется, но оно полностью пустое. Что с этим делать?

Пишу с помощью библиотеки `eel`.

### Проект имеет структуру:

```
project_folder -----
                    |web -----
                             | index.html
                             | css.style
                             | js.js
                    |main.py
```

### Вёрстка:

```js
function updateToDo(){
    
}

function addToDo(){
    let todo, time;
    todo = document.getElementById("todo").values;
    time = document.getElementById("time").values;
    console.log(time,todo);
}

documen.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", addToDo);
documen.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", updateToDo);
```

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main *{
    margin: 10px;
}

#input{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#input *{
    margin: 2px;
}

#spis{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Первая проба JS с Python и SQLite</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main" id="main">
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <div id="input">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Дело" id="todo">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Время" id="time">
            <button id="but">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="spis">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Код Python:

```
import eel
import sqlite3
import os

def createDB():
    con = sqlite3.connect(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/ToDoList.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.executescript("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ToDoList` (
            `ToDo`  TEXT NOT NULL,
            `Time`  TEXT NOT NULL
            );
        """)
    con.commit()

createDB()

eel.init('web')

@eel.expose
def add_DB(val):
    con = sqlite3.connect(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/ToDoList.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO ToDoList VALUES (?,?)", val)
    con.commit()

@eel.expose
def return_DB():
    con = sqlite3.connect(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/ToDoList.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ToDoList")
    res = cur.fetchall()
    con.commit()
    return res

eel.start('index.html', size=(700, 700), port=500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял свою ошибку - не садитесь писать код после того, как ночи 3 не поспите XD

С недосыпа перепутал папки и писал html не в том index.html.

PS Всем спокойной ночи)